# Android: Collection.sort() mismatch using Comparator

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to arrange an array of movies in alphabetical order, ignoring case. My application allows the user to add his/her own entry into an already initialized array of movies in a ListView. Here is the snippet:

```
            Lab7_082588FetchDetails newMovie = new Lab7_082588FetchDetails();
            IgnoreCaseComparator ignoreCase = new IgnoreCaseComparator();
            newMovie.setTitle(data.getStringExtra(Lab7_082588Edit.TITLE_STRING));
            newMovie.setGross(data.getStringExtra(Lab7_082588Edit.GROSS_STRING));
            newMovie.setDate(data.getStringExtra(Lab7_082588Edit.DATE_STRING));
            results.add(newMovie);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Collections.sort(results, ignoreCase);
```

However the .sort portion of the last line gives an error message:

```
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Lab7_082588FetchDetails>, IgnoreCaseComparator)
```

Also, this is my IgnoreCaseComparator:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

class IgnoreCaseComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String strA, String strB) {
        return strA.compareToIgnoreCase(strB);
    }  
}
```

And my Fetch Details Class:

```
public class Lab7_082588FetchDetails implements Comparable<Lab7_082588FetchDetails> {

private String title;
private String gross;
private String date;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getGross() {
    return gross;
}

public void setGross(String gross) {
    this.gross = gross;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Lab7_082588FetchDetails another) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.compareTo(another.title);
}

}
```

How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
implements Comparator<String>
```

Your comparator accepts String only, but your list has `Lab7_082588FetchDetails` object.

Change it to implements `Comparator<Lab7_082588FetchDetails>`

and change compare method to

```
public int compare(Lab7_082588FetchDetails objA, Lab7_082588FetchDetails objB) {
        return objA.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(objB.getTitle());
    }
```

Comment: I have tried changing Comparator to accept Objects, but it does a Force Close on me.

Comment: it works perfectly. I can't believe I never thought of this. Much appreciated help sir thinsteep!

Comment: Glad it helped. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Either use comparator or comparable

Comparable : when you can change class structure to add compareTo method

comparator: If you can't change class structure.

Also both should be passed with the object that needs to be compared.
In your case comparator is written for `String` and you are passing `Lab7_082588FetchDetails`